# Circular imports Python

Tags: python, circular-dependency

I've read [this post](https://stackabuse.com/python-circular-imports) about circular imports in Python. It describes the following scenario and argues that this raises an error when run:

```
# module1
import module2

def function1():
    module2.function2()

def function3():
    print('Goodbye, World!')
```

```
# module2
import module1

def function2():
    print('Hello, World!')
    module1.function3()
```

```
# __init__.py
import module1

module1.function1()
```

But when I run this (Python 3.95), it runs perfectly fine. The post is pretty old and it doesn't specify the Python version it uses. Maybe there was some change in latter Pythons that support this?

Comment: This might be a silly question but is the code you pasted here in different modules? or is it just one file with comments?

Comment: Those are different modules

Comment: I tried it on python 3.5.2 and it works there as well

Comment: The post is from 2017 and clearly using <2.7 or outright wrong. All the newer import systems would consistently load both modules before actually calling anything in `__init__`

Comment: I might be wrong, but I think circular imports are an issue when you use relative imports. If you use absolute imports, then your code works (or at least should). Take a look at [this link](https://agilno.com/why-cyclic-dependency-errors-occur-a-look-into-the-python-import-mechanism/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simplified sequence of events that happen in the code in Python 3:

1. `__init__.py` starts running

   - An empty [`__main__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html) module is added to [`sys.modules`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.modules)
2. `import module1` starts loading `module1.py`

   - An empty `module1` module is added to `sys.modules`
3. `import module2` starts loading `module2.py`

   - An empty `module2` module is added to `sys.modules`
4. `module2.function2` is created and added to [`module2.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__)

   - The fact that `function2` references names in `module1` does not affect the creation of the function object in any way
5. `module2` is fully loaded and execution returns to `module1`
6. `module1.function1` and `module1.function3` are created and added to `module1.__dict__`

   - Again, it does not matter what names the functions reference because they are not being called. `AttributeError` and `NameError` can be raised at runtime if necessary.
7. `module1` is fully loaded and execution returns to `__main__`
8. `module1.function` runs successfully, since all the names it references are resolvable.

As you can see, there are no circular import issues in this particular sequence of imports because `module1` and `module2` do not attempt to call each other's functions. The current import system allows both modules to load before the functions are called.

The post you mention is from 2017, and must be using a version of python from before 3.0. A hint is found in the link in the following quote, which links to the python-2.x docs:

> This approach doesn't contradict Python syntax, as the [Python documentation says](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html): "It is customary but not required to place all import statements at the beginning of a module (or script, for that matter)".

The paragraph after that is a bit misleading by the way:

> The Python documentation also says that it is advisable to use `import X`, instead of other statements, such as `from module import *`, or `from module import a,b,c`.

While star imports are certainly discouraged, specific-name imports of the form `from module import a,b,c` are generally very much encouraged with few exceptions.